# Can I set a default host_vars file for all hosts on a given Ansible environment?

Tags: ansible

I have a project with 3 environment. Development(Vangrant), staging(cloud) and production(cloud). I would like to have all environment variables my playbook uses to be in one file for each environment. It works fine if I have one server per environment as below:

```
my_proj/
  src/
  provisioner/
    host_vars/
      dev-vm.yml
    staging/
      host_vars/
        staging-web.yml
      inventory
    prod/
      host_vars/
        prod-web.yml
      inventory
    playbook.yml
  Vagrantfile
```

This way my Vagrant uses `ansible_local` to automatically apply the playbook and the playbook uses variables from `/my_proj/provisioner/host_vars/dev-vm.yml`

Staging/Production can be provisioned from within the Vagrant itself or any other computer with Ansible using the command `ansible-playbook provisioner/playbook.yml -i provisioner/staging`.

My problem is when I add multiple servers on my staging/production inventory file. I have to duplicate `my_proj/provisioner/staging/host_vars/web-staging.yml` for each new server. Is there a way to have a "default" env_vars file per environment?

For example, If my staging inventory has 3 servers [`staging-web`, `staging-cli-01`, `staging-cli-02`] I don't wanna to have 3 similar files withing `my_proj/provisioner/host_vars/` as `staging-web.yml`, `staging-cli-01.yml`, `staging-cli-02.yml`. Ideally I would just have `my_proj/provisioner/host_vars/all.yml`

Any idea in how to accomplish it or suggestion of better way to organize the project?

Comment: There are inventory groups and their vars for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If I understand your question correctly, and your requirements match the way your question is written (i.e. you only need the group behaviour in staging and production), then you can add a `group_vars` dir under `staging` and `production` and within there, place an `all.yml`, moving all your vars into this file.

When you use `-i`to specify your inventory file, the contents of `group_vars`, like `host_vars` will be loaded.

You can further refine this approach by placing your hosts into groups within your inventory and replacing `all.yml` with `<group_name>.yml`.

Beware however, if you employ this technique for your vagrant hosts (i.e. place a `group_vars` directory in the same directory as your playbook), you will likely not get the results you expect. This is due to group_vars at the playbook level having higher precedence than those at the inventory level.

See the [Ansible Variables docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) for more info.

Comment: Great, I kept my Vagrant with `host_vars` and for staging/production just, renamed folders `host_vars` to `group_vars` and kept a `all.yml` withing it... on staging/prod inventory I created a group called `all` with all servers.